# Не вызывается OnKeyDown в моем TextureView

Tags: java, android

Реализую свой TextureView и мне там надо клавиатуру вызывать и обрабатывать а onKeyDown не вызывается, вызываю клавиатуру через метод test, всю реализацию не привожу потому что очень большая. Что интерестно вызывается метод из интерфейса View.OnUnhandledKeyEventListener, но это только для android с 9 версии, а мне надо чтобы работало с android 5. Знаю что это не из-за onTouchListener он тоже не вызывается когда на клавиатуру жмешь Еще у меня релизованы MoveDetector и ScaleDetector:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
public class XlsSheetView extends TextureView implements /*View.OnUnhandledKeyEventListener, */View.OnKeyListener {
 @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        nowEvent = event;
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            L.i("down");
            //directionSelect = 0;
            scroller.forceFinished(true);
        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            L.i("move");
            if(isMoveSelectNow) { //значит идет выделение проверяем палец на краю экрана
                int touchX = (int) event.getX();
                int touchY = (int) event.getY();
                int measuredWidth = getMeasuredWidth() - 20;
                int measuredHeight = getMeasuredHeight() - 20;
                int distanceScrollX =(int)FIXED_CELL_WIDTH + (int)(0.5 * FIXED_CELL_WIDTH);
                int distanceScrollY = (int)FIXED_CELL_HEIGHT + (int)(0.5 * FIXED_CELL_HEIGHT);
            
                if(touchX > measuredWidth && touchY < measuredHeight) {
            
                    isMoveSelectOnBorder = true;
                    startScrollAsync(distanceScrollX, distanceScrollY);
                } else if(touchX < measuredWidth && touchY > measuredHeight) {
                    isMoveSelectOnBorder = true;
                    startScrollAsync(distanceScrollX, distanceScrollY);
                } else if(touchX > measuredWidth && touchY > measuredHeight) {
                    isMoveSelectOnBorder = true;
                    startScrollAsync(distanceScrollX, distanceScrollY);
                }
            }
            moveSelect(event);
        }
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            isMoveSelectOnBorder = false;
        }
        moveDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        scaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
   
     @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        char unicodeChar = (char)event.getUnicodeChar();
        testStr += ""+unicodeChar;
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyMultiple(int keyCode, int repeatCount, KeyEvent event) {
        return super.onKeyMultiple(keyCode, repeatCount, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyShortcut(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return super.onKeyShortcut(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }

    /*@Override
    public void addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener(OnUnhandledKeyEventListener listener) {
        super.addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener(listener);
    }*/

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    public void test() {
        setOnKeyListener(this);
       /* addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener(this);*/
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        L.i("isActive="+imm.isActive());
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
        L.i("isActive2="+imm.isActive());
    }
}
```

Comment: Может потому что вы назначили слушатель, а события ждёте не в его методе (`onKey(View, int,  KeyEvent)`), а в методах `View`?

Comment: Может немного поздно, но нет это не из-за этого я перебирал просто варианты но нигде не работает :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что на моем TextureView не висел фокус. Решил проблему так:

```
 this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
 if(this.requestFocus()) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
}
```